# How to get confirmed list (IEnumerable) in HttpPost method?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

in my ASP .Net MVC 2 application the user is shown a list of items and must click confirm before the list is persisted to the database.

When the user clicks confirm, in the HttpPost method the parameter is null. Everything works until the HttpPost method is called. At this point the list that  must be persisted is null.

How do I get the confirmed values ?

I've tried using TempData in the HttpGet method but TempData is also null in the HttpPost method.

Here is the controller code.

```
    public ActionResult Confirm()
    {
        List<ConfirmVehicleModel> vehicles = GetAllVehicles();
        return View(vehicles);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Confirm(List<ConfirmVehicleModel> model)
    {

        //model is null, why ?

        UploadVehiclesModelService service = new Models.UploadVehiclesModelService();
        service.StoreVehicles(model, User.Identity.Name);

        return RedirectToAction("Index", "UploadVehicles");
    }
```

And here is the Confirm view:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<IEnumerable<RM.Application.Models.ConfirmVehicleModel>>" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="TitleContent" runat="server">
    Confirm
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
<h2>
    Confirm that the vehicles below should be added.</h2>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>
            ReferenceType
        </th>
        <th>
            ReferenceName
        </th>
    </tr>
    <% foreach (var item in Model)
       { %>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <%= Html.Encode(item.ReferenceType) %>
        </td>
        <td>
            <%= Html.Encode(item.ReferenceName) %>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <% } %>
</table>
 <div>
    <% using (Html.BeginForm())
       { %>
    <input type="submit" value="Confirm" />
    |
    <%= Html.ActionLink("Back to upload form", "Index") %>
    <% } %>
</div>
</asp:Content>
```

Thanks for any help,

Kind regards

Bob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your HTML.BeginForm() is out of place it should surround the values you wish to pass.

Try:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
<h2>Confirm that the vehicles below should be added.</h2>
<% using (Html.BeginForm())
   { %>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>
                ReferenceType
            </th>
            <th>
                ReferenceName
            </th>
        </tr>
        <% foreach (var item in Model)
           { %>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <%= Html.Encode(item.ReferenceType) %>
                <%= Html.HiddenFor(model => item.ReferenceType)%>
            </td>
            <td>
                <%= Html.Encode(item.ReferenceName) %>
                <%= Html.HiddenFor(model => item.ReferenceName)%>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <% } %>
    </table>
 <div>
    <input type="submit" value="Confirm" />
    |
    <%= Html.ActionLink("Back to upload form", "Index") %>
    <% } %>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Nicholas, thank you for your reply. I moved the Html.BeginForm as you suggest. The parameter List<ConfirmVehicleModel> mode is still null. I also tried FormCollection as the parameter but that is also null. Do I need to use LABEL elements ? How does the FORM element know which data to post back ? Regards Bob

Comment: @bobentelect - You can 'embed' the values within the form as hidden values using Html.HiddenFor

Answer (score 0):

Nicholas advice helped. I replaced the foreach loop with a for loop and used `Html.HiddenFor`.

```
  <% for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++)
           { %>
        <%= Html.HiddenFor(model=>model[i].ReferenceType) %>
        <%= Html.HiddenFor(model=>model[i].ReferenceName) %>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <%= Html.Encode(Model[i].ReferenceType) %>
            </td>
            <td>
                <%= Html.Encode(Model[i].ReferenceName) %>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <% } %>
```

I also changed the top line of the the view to (previously IEnumerable, now List).

```
  <%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<List<RM.Application.Models.ConfirmVehicleModel>>" %>\\
```

The `List<ConfirmVehicleModel>` model parameter of the `HttpPost` method is now populated.